# Does outlook have delivery receipts?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I know that outlook can require "read receipts" from the recipient of an email but is there anyway to set up your account so that your account automatically sends "delivery receipts" to anyone who sends an email to you?

Comment: there is no such thing as a "delivery receipt."  I suppose you could create an Outlook rule to reply to every incoming message.

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Get-delivery-and-read-receipt-confirmations-a34bf70a-4c2c-4461-b2a1-12e4a7a92141

Answer (score 1):

In Outlook options, go to Mail -> Tracking. There, you can set all required options, including "Always send a read receipt".